# grpc installion error while installing firebase-admin for node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase-admin

i recently updated my firebase-admin dependency from 5.5.1 to 5.8.2 and tried installing the new dependencies, however, it fails and i can no longer deploy my cloud functions which are there in the directory.

The package.json file is :

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase experimental:functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "~5.8.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.8.1"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

The error log is as follows:

```
> grpc@1.8.4 install C:\Users\kusha\FirebaseWaitlistFunctions\functions\node_modules\grpc
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(undefined): https://storage.googleapis.com/grpc-precompiled-binaries/node/grpc/v1.8.4/node-v59-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.8.4 and node@9.4.0 (node-v59 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "C:\Program Files\Python36\", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Users\kusha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\kusha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\kusha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:166:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.15063
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\kusha\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=C:\\Users\\kusha\\FirebaseWaitlistFunctions\\functions\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v59-win32-x64-unknown\\grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\kusha\\FirebaseWaitlistFunctions\\functions\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v59-win32-x64-unknown"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\kusha\FirebaseWaitlistFunctions\functions\node_modules\grpc
gyp ERR! node -v v9.4.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\kusha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=C:\Users\kusha\FirebaseWaitlistFunctions\functions\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v59-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=C:\Users\kusha\FirebaseWaitlistFunctions\functions\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v59-win32-x64-unknown' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\kusha\FirebaseWaitlistFunctions\functions\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:160:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:943:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:220:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.15063
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\kusha\\FirebaseWaitlistFunctions\\functions\\node_modules\\grpc\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\kusha\FirebaseWaitlistFunctions\functions\node_modules\grpc
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v9.4.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.39
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\kusha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=C:\Users\kusha\FirebaseWaitlistFunctions\functions\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v59-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=C:\Users\kusha\FirebaseWaitlistFunctions\functions\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v59-win32-x64-unknown' (1)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! grpc@1.8.4 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.8.4 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\kusha\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-01-31T18_47_14_943Z-debug.log
```

My windows version is 10.0.15063

The python error shown seems stupid as i have python installed and have the PYTHON variable set and also have it in the path variable. Running a python command from anywhere in cmd does get me into the python console part.

I tried updating firebase tools to the latest version 3.17.4 but got the same warnings there, however it said that the dependency there was optional.

I updated my Node.js to 9.4.0 the latest i found on the official site.
Update npm to 5.6.0  using npm install -g npm

I am unfortunately not a Node.js developer and this is my first venture on it because of having to use firebase-functions. Kindly point me in the correct direction as i don't know how to solve this. There is no issue with my function code as it was working correctly before i tried updating the dependencies.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For people looking at this, At the time of writing this, the only solution i have found to make this error go away is disabling the antivirus services for a while.

I have seen this happen when my Kaspersky antivirus was running. This issue has already been raised in multiple places by multiple people in the github library.
Most of them have found that disabling the antivirus makes the issue go away.

Solution works with functions 1.0.1